# 404 Not Found | NGINX -- trying to deploy client side React code to Heroku and Webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-router, yarnpkg

I am trying to deploy my React js app (uses react-router v4 and webpack) to heroku.

Everything builds without errors according to heroku as its going through its deployment scripts (see below) unfortunately when actually visiting the page it says page is not found.

originally Heroku was giving build errors but I was able to eliminate the build errors, now that it successfully builds I dont know where to troubleshoot next.

my entire project code:
https://github.com/aronlmin/react_doesnt_work/blob/master/webpack.config.js

```
aronlilland:backbone_cac_client (master)$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 315 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: 
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Multipack
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Node.js
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=development
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 6.x via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.10.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.10
remote:        Resolving yarn version (latest) via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (0.23.4)...
remote:        Installed yarn 0.23.4
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        !     node_modules checked into source control
remote:        https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
remote:        
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v0.23.4
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        warning fsevents@1.1.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.1.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        $ npm run build
remote:        
remote:        > backbone_cac_client@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_c94a0cec125e5c3a562ef7e154841a47
remote:        > webpack -p
remote:        
remote:        Hash: d28b920eb76ccc581c9a
remote:        Version: webpack 2.5.0
remote:        Time: 13581ms
remote:        Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
remote:        bundle.js     386 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
remote:        index.html  383 bytes          [emitted]
remote:        [0] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [1] ./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js 1.63 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [26] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [35] ./~/react/lib/React.js 3.32 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [43] ./~/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js 9.11 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [67] ./~/react-grid-system/build/index.js 1.32 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [182] ./src/app/App.jsx 4.01 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [183] ./~/react-tap-event-plugin/src/injectTapEventPlugin.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [185] ./src/app/Router.jsx 3.75 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [191] ./src/index.js 723 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [310] ./~/material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js 2.15 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [342] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js 5.14 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [405] ./~/react-router-dom/BrowserRouter.js 2.57 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [428] ./~/react-tap-event-plugin/src/defaultClickRejectionStrategy.js 151 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [446] ./src/app/App.css 1 kB {0} [built]
remote:        + 437 hidden modules
remote:        Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
remote:        [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 694 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        Done in 43.06s.
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-inner-buildpack.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: React.js (create-react-app)
remote:        Using existing `static.json`
remote:        Enabling runtime environment variables
remote: 
remote: > backbone_cac_client@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_c94a0cec125e5c3a562ef7e154841a47
remote: > webpack -p
remote: 
remote: Hash: d28b920eb76ccc581c9a
remote: Version: webpack 2.5.0
remote: Time: 13451ms
remote:      Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
remote:  bundle.js     386 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
remote: index.html  383 bytes          [emitted]         
remote:    [0] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
remote:    [1] ./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js 1.63 kB {0} [built]
remote:   [26] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
remote:   [35] ./~/react/lib/React.js 3.32 kB {0} [built]
remote:   [43] ./~/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js 9.11 kB {0} [built]
remote:   [67] ./~/react-grid-system/build/index.js 1.32 kB {0} [built]
remote:  [182] ./src/app/App.jsx 4.01 kB {0} [built]
remote:  [183] ./~/react-tap-event-plugin/src/injectTapEventPlugin.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
remote:  [185] ./src/app/Router.jsx 3.75 kB {0} [built]
remote:  [191] ./src/index.js 723 bytes {0} [built]
remote:  [310] ./~/material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js 2.15 kB {0} [built]
remote:  [342] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js 5.14 kB {0} [built]
remote:  [405] ./~/react-router-dom/BrowserRouter.js 2.57 kB {0} [built]
remote:  [428] ./~/react-tap-event-plugin/src/defaultClickRejectionStrategy.js 151 bytes {0} [built]
remote:  [446] ./src/app/App.css 1 kB {0} [built]
remote:     + 437 hidden modules
remote: Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
remote:        [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
remote:        [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 694 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
remote:        [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Static HTML
remote:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
remote:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
remote: 100  838k  100  838k    0     0  17.5M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17.8M
remote: -----> Installed directory to /app/bin
remote: Using release configuration from last framework (Static HTML).
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 31.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v5
remote:        https://cacbackboneclient.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/cacbackboneclient.git
   9c5b5c6..d6cd99c  master -> master
```

Comment: Does webpack produce valid files when you run it locally? Does your site work locally?

Comment: yep, works locally just fine -- however I dont know how to test the npm run build version, the development version works fine

Comment: Webpack often uses a different build configuration for the local version and the distribution version. The `npm run build` should be emitting everything to a folder. The folder should have an index.html file. Just open that in your browser. If everything Webpacked correctly, the site should run like it does for the dev version (although without any hot reloading features). I'm not sure if this is the issue, but it's something to check.

Comment: Webpack compiles everything into a folder called "dist" with a `bundle.js` file and an `index.html` file.... I can ssh into heroku and see that it exists, but unfortunately it doesnt work on the live server...

Comment: Please forgive me if my questions are just showing my ignorance of Heroku (I haven't used it - most of my cloud experience is on AWS). Your files are being emitted... Interesting... Is there a way to verify the nginx proxy configuration? Check permissions and firewall settings? Error logs?

Comment: Contacted the Heroku Support team, the heroku buildpack I was using was a third party buildpack I found off of google, not an official buildpack. Their buildpack for react is still in beta, but they supplied me with their beta buildpack and it was able to be deployed after I added a config setting specifying my index.html root folder path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was a buildpack issue, the buildpack I was using (a specific third party buildpack recommended by a third party service to deploy a default bare bones react app)

My app was unable to be located because the buildpack wasnt pointing the server to my index.html file inside the dist folder I had created, it was looking for a different folder entirely

PLEASE TAKE NOTE

if you are having deployment issues with ANY single page application, use the following buildpack and make sure you are specifying the root folder of your bundled application

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

Answer (score 0):

Alilland's answer is correct, however note that to deploy a static app in heroku 22, you'll need the newer nginx static buildpack:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx